# How to delete multiple rows at once in a for loop using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand that if you happen to have to the `start` and `howManyRowsToDelete`, one can use `deleteRows(start, howManyRowsToDelete)`, but how to delete multiple rows at once in a for loop, or right after it!?

```
for (let n = entregasBD.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
  for (let a = 0; a < retirarItens.length; a++) {
    if (entregasBD[n][8] == noEntrega && entregasBD[n][9] == 'Pendente' && entregasBD[n][0] == retirarItens[a][0]) {
      let row = n + 1;
      let qtdMov = retirarItens[a][9]; 
      let qtdPendente = entregasBD[n][5]; 
      let qtdEntrega = entregasBD[n][4];
      qtdPendente = qtdPendente + qtdMov;
      qtdEntrega = qtdEntrega - qtdMov;
      console.log('Qtd de Entrega Final: ' + qtdEntrega)
      if (qtdEntrega == 0) {
        sheetBDEnt.deleteRow(row);//These calls are what I'm trying to avoid
      } else {
        sheetBDEnt.getRange(row, 5, 1, 2).setValues([=[qtdEntrega, qtdPendente]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate your attention.

Comment: By guessing the values of `entregasBD`, `retirarItens`, and `noEntrega`, I posted a modified your script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I might not be able to correctly understand your actual Spreadsheet and your actual goal you expect. I'm worried about this. So, when this modified script was not useful, I apologize. At that time, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet, I thought that it will help to modify the script.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a demo sheet with dummy values we can work with? I agree with @Tanaike that it is pretty hard to imagine your actual spreadsheet with the provided script above.

Comment: Hi, @DiegoSanchez! Thanks! You guys are right! My bad thinking this'd be clear enough with the script only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `how to delete multiple rows at once in a for loop, or right after it!?`, you want to delete the rows by one request.

In this case, how about the following modification?

Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet. So, by guessing the values of `entregasBD`, `retirarItens`, and `noEntrega`, I modified your script.

#### Modified script:

In order to achieve your goal, in this script, Sheets API is used. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
// do something.
// Please put your script retrieving the values of `entregasBD`, `retirarItens` and `noEntrega`.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = "###"; // Please set your sheet ID.

const obj = retirarItens.reduce((o, r) => (o[r[0]] = r[9], o), {});
const requests = entregasBD.reduce((ar, [a, , , , e, f, , , i, j], row) => {
  if (i == noEntrega && j == 'Pendente' && obj[a]) {
    let qtdMov = obj[a];
    let qtdPendente = f;
    let qtdEntrega = e;
    qtdPendente = qtdPendente + qtdMov;
    qtdEntrega = qtdEntrega - qtdMov;
    if (qtdEntrega == 0) {
      ar.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: row, endIndex: row + 1, dimension: "ROWS" } } });
    } else {
      ar.push({ updateCells: { start: { sheetId, rowIndex: row, columnIndex: 4 }, rows: [{ values: [{ userEnteredValue: { numberValue: qtdEntrega } }, { userEnteredValue: { numberValue: qtdPendente } },] }], fields: "userEnteredValue" } });
    }
  }
  return ar;
}, []).reverse();
if (requests.length == 0) return;
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, spreadsheetId);
```

- In this modification, the rows are deleted by Sheets API. And also, the values are put to the rows using Sheets API. By this, all requests can be done by one API call.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I might not be able to correctly understand your actual Spreadsheet and your actual goal you expect. I'm worried about this. So, when this modified script was not useful, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet, I thought that it will help to modify the script.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: Thank you! On point! Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question.

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. If this modified script was useful, I'm glad.